# Writing a Protocol in a swift Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols

Im trying to write a Swift framework with a protocol used for a delegate method. I've made the protocol public, but when I add my framework to my project, the project spits out the following error 
`ViewController.swift:15:83: No type named 'MyControllerDelegate' in module 'MyModule'`

```
import MyModule

class ViewController: UIViewController, MyModule.MyControllerDelegate {
```

Any help in these regards would be appreciated.

Update: not sure if this makes any difference but some of the object types in the protocol are defined by another framework...

Comment: Show the code for defining protocol MyControllerDelegate

Comment: It seems like the compiler cannot infer that you are not defining inheritance, but conformance to a protocol. Have you actually defined all functions/properties needed for the protocol conformance? Btw there's no need for the explicit namespacing unless `MyControllerDelegate` has the same name as an already existing protocol.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes: I've implemented all the functions needed for the conformance -> I previously had the project as a source submodule... but Im trying to convert to a compiled framework to save build time on the CI

Comment: the delegate name is in deed unique, but removing the namespace changes the error to "use of undeclared type 'MyControllerDelegate'"

Comment: What if you put all delegate methods into an extension for `ViewController`, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Is the protocol file added to the correct target ?